# Symfony 2 session and soap (web services)

Tags: session, symfony, soap

I am using Symfony 2 with Soap. I passing the parameter to the Symfony with the soap. My plan is that I went to a session, but the the backup fails.

This is standard save width symfony (First run):

```
$sess = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
$sess->set('parameter', 'parameter');
echo $sess->get('parameter'); //This whill write 'parameter' when send data with soap
```

When I remove the set function, the session will be lost than second soap run (Second run):

```
$sess = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
//$sess->set('parameter', 'parameter');
echo $sess->get('parameter'); //Do not write off anything
```

It says the symfony.com on that session is suitable for:

> ... store information about the user (be it a real person using a browser, a bot, or a web service) ...

Answer (score 0):

Session is identified (per standard) via the PHPSESSID cookie or query parameter. So if you want to have a standard browser session your soap client must store the PHPSESSID cookie he gets at the first request and send it in further request or with the query param.

**But** a webservice should be stateless. If you need to identify an client over request, use OAuth tokens. Take a look at the [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle).